# subquery must return only one column error occurs when trying to run sql script

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to set the "open jobs" column in user to the result of a select query

this is what i've tried but and error occurs

```
UPDATE
    "user"
SET
    open_jobs = (
        SELECT
            u."_id_",
            COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE jc.status IN ('Pending', 'Work Started')) AS open_cnt
        FROM
            job_card jc
        LEFT JOIN "user" u ON u."_id_" = jc.technicians_fk
    GROUP BY
        u."_id_")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest removing the `FILTER` entirely and you want a correlation clause instead of a `JOIN`:

```
update "user" u
    set open_jobs = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS open_cnt
                     FROM job_card jc 
                     WHERE u."_id_" = jc.technicians_fk AND
                           jc.status IN ('Pending', 'Work Started')
                    );
```

The `WHERE` clause may be more efficient.  If there are no matches, the `COUNT(*)` returns `0`.

Your version of the subquery is almost what you want . . . if you move it to a `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE "user" u
    SET open_jobs = COALESCE(jc.cnt)
    FROM (SELECT u."_id_", COUNT(*) as cnt FILTER (WHERE jc.status IN ('Pending', 'Work Started')) AS open_cnt
          FROM "user" u LEFT JOIN
               job_card jc
               ON u."_id_" = jc.technicians_fk
          GROUP BY u."_id_"
         ) jc
    WHERE jc."_id_" = u."_id_";
```

One important difference is that `"user"` is the first table for the `LEFT JOIN`, to ensure that you get all users.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery has multiple columns and giving multiple rows. Use the following query:

```
UPDATE "user" SET OPEN_JOBS = 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER ( -- removed the u."_id_"
 WHERE JC.STATUS IN (
    'Pending',
    'Work Started'
) ) AS OPEN_CNT
  FROM JOB_CARD   JC -- user table is not required here
WHERE U."_id_" = JC.TECHNICIANS_FK) -- this will make sure that your query is correlated
```